# Rails test error in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner trying to learn rails. When i tried to run the "rails test" command, I get this message. I don't understand what this message is :/

```
rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 46753
/Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': /Users/..../test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in `block in require_files'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `require_files'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:94:in `plugin_rails_init'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:81:in `block in init_plugins'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:79:in `each'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:79:in `init_plugins'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:130:in `run'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:77:in `run'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/..../.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It means what it says, `static_pages_controller_test.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)`.  So there's probably a syntax error in the file named in the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is actually telling you exactly where the issue is.

On line 26 of your `static_pages_controller_test.rb` file, you're missing an `end`.

```
...static_pages_controller_test.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you likely have either ommitted an `end` from your `static_pages_controller_test.rb` file. Or, you have an extra `end` in that file.

If you look at the error:

```
..../test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:26 syntax error,   
     unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)`
```

It's telling you that something is amiss on line 26. 
Then `syntax error`, means you have typed something incorrectly. 
It then says `unexpected end-of-input` which means that the parser couldn't figure out where to end the method, and the reason for that is that it was `expecting keyword_end`, which means there is an `end` keyword missing.